# Sieve of Eratosthenes buggy implementation

Tags: c++

I am starting with c++ and i wanted to implemented sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

vector<unsigned long long int> sieveOfEratosthenes(unsigned long long int min, unsigned long long int max) {
    vector<unsigned long long int> result;

    if (max <= 1) return result;
    if (min < 1) return result;


    if (max == 2) {
        result.push_back(max);
        return result;
    }

    if(min == 1) {
        min = 2; // skip 1 as it is not prime
    }

    bool primes[(max - min)+ 1];
    //Assume all number within range are prime and filter later
    for (unsigned long long int  i = min; i <= max ; i++) {
        primes[i] = true;
    }

    for (unsigned long long int  i = min; i < sqrt(max); i++ ) {
        if(primes[i]) {
            for (unsigned long long int  j = i; i*j <= max; j++) {
                primes[i*j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (unsigned long long int  i = min; i <= max ; i++) {
        if (primes[i]) {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return result;

}

void print(vector<unsigned long long int> result) {
    for ( auto &i : result ) {
        cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int start_s=clock();
    vector<unsigned long long int> result = sieveOfEratosthenes(1,1000000);
    int stop_s=clock();
    cout << "time: " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << " ms" << endl;
    print(result);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run it for `1-100` , i get correct result but for `1-1000000` i get `1000000` as well which is incorrect.

**Edit**

I have refactor the code according to C++ standard with suggestions from @badola and @Ben Voigt.The code is also available on [Github](https://github.com/khavishbhundoo/sieveOfEratosthenes)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using u_big = unsigned long long int;

vector<u_big> sieveOfEratosthenes(u_big min, u_big max) {
    vector<u_big> result;

    if (max <= 1 || min < 1 ) return result;

    if(min == 1) {
        min = 2; // skip 1 as it is not prime
    }

    if (max == 2) {
        result.push_back(max);
        return result;
    }


    /*
     * Declare a vector of boolean and ser all value to true
     * Consider all numbers to be prime at this point
     */
    vector<bool> primes(min + (max - min) + 1,true);

    auto sqrt_max = (u_big) sqrt(max);

    for (auto i = min; i < sqrt_max; i++ ) {
        if(primes.at(i)) {
            /*
             * Filter out non primes
             * Multiples of positive numbers cannot be primes
             */
            for (auto  j = i; i*j <= max; j++) {
                primes.at(i*j) = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto  i = min; i <= max ; i++) {
        if (primes.at(i)) {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return result;

}

void print(vector<u_big> result) {
    for ( auto const &i : result ) {
        cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

void save(const string &filename,vector<u_big> result) {
    ofstream outFile(filename);
    for (const auto &p : result)  outFile << p << "\n";

}

int main() {
    unsigned long long int min,max;
    cout << "Enter minimum : ";
    cin >> min;
    cout << "\nEnter maximum : ";
    cin >> max;
    int start_s=clock();
    vector<u_big> result = sieveOfEratosthenes(min,max);
    int stop_s=clock();
    cout << "Runtime to generate primes : " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Number of primes : " <<  result.size() << endl;
    cout << "Primes saved to sieve.txt" << endl;
    save("primes.txt", result);
    //print(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever used a debugger before?

Comment: @YSC yes but i can't see what is wrong with the code

Comment: Some of the code is not valid C++.  Did you compile with warnings enabled?

Comment: Worth noting that a million `bool`s can easily consume all of your available Automatic storage.

Comment: Unrelated: if you are going for speed, `sqrt(max)` in a loop can be utterly murderous.  Optimizer should be able to compute once and cache, but you may still find `i*i < max` to be zippier.

Comment: I am using Clion on Windows and I have 16gb of ram.I haven't add extra flags for warnings

Comment: @user4581301  yes thanks for the tip.

Comment: I fixed the warnings, and it works correctly on my system.

Comment: Assuming vanilla Windows with the default stack size of 1 MB,  1,000,000 bools dooms the program.

Comment: @Eljay I am using c++ 11 .Here is what i see https://i.gyazo.com/7ec7ddc232875581e9de63ea671c5d46.png

Comment: @user2650277 • change `primes` to be a `vector<bool>` of the appropriate size, and access the elements using the `primes.at(i)` so you can see the exception when you go out of bounds.  That should fix your code.  May have to use an `int` or `char` for a bool, since `vector<bool>` is specialized in a way that may not work here.

Comment: A note on @Eljay 's comment. When you are done testing, consider replacing `at` with `[]`. The extra bounds testing done by `at` takes a tiny amount of time, but it adds up. Once you have confirmed that the program does not go out of bounds you can remove the need for the test and recover the time.

Comment: This line is not C++: `bool primes[(max - min)+ 1];`  Use `vector<bool>` or `vector<char>` instead.  This has several helpful effects: (0) It's allowed in standard C++ not compiler-specific (1) The memory comes from the heap instead of the stack (2) Allocation failures act predictably (throwing an exception) instead of being at the whim of the non-Standard compiler design.

Comment: @BenVoigt and others thanks a lot for the code cleanup and wonderful explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem, you are accessing index outside the allocated memory of your array.
You need to initialize your vector to have (max + 1) locations.

Please prefer `std::vector` over c-style array and use `at()` operator, and your program will throw an exception whenever it runs over the maximum allocated index.

Exception raised : `terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector`

I refactored your code to suit to C++11, since in the comments you have mentioned using a C++11 based compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using u_big = unsigned long long int; // Whatever you want, please don't type it 
                                      // in multiple locations, too hard to update the code
                                      // Prefer using, from C++11

std::vector<u_big> sieveOfEratosthenes(u_big min, u_big max) {
    std::vector<u_big> result;

    if (max <= 1 || min < 1) return result;

    if (max == 2) {
        result.push_back(max);
        return result;
    }

    if(min == 1) min = 2; // skip 1 as it is not prime

    std::vector<bool> primes(max + 1, true); // set them all to true while creating vector
    // here was the real problem
    // you were actually accessing (max + 1) elements in your array
    // but were requesting for (max - min + 1) elements 

    for (auto i = min; i < sqrt(max); ++i) {
        if(primes.at(i)) { 
        // as suggested in the comments, use at()
        // you would have witnessed  your code throw exception
            for (auto j = i; i*j <= max; ++j) {
                primes.at(i * j) = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (primes.at(i)) {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename Iterable>
void print(Iterable const & result) {
    for (auto const & i : result ) { // please use const &, if not modifying
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto start_s = clock();
    auto result = sieveOfEratosthenes(1,1000000);
    //auto result = sieveOfEratosthenes(1,100);
    auto stop_s = clock();
    std::cout << "time: " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 
    << " ms" << std::endl;
    print(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Please be kind enough to tell me my mistakes. I will fix my answer, if I have made a mistake.

Comment: I figured out my mistakes from the comments but thanks a lot for your refactoring.I was assessing from `min` to `max`.If you use `max + 1` won't you reserve a lots of unused memory.

Comment: I don't think this will acquire a lot of space, because `std::vector<bool>` is generally a specialised form of `std::vector`. It is designed to be space efficient. Please read about it : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

`std::vector<bool>` is a possibly space-efficient specialization of std::vector for the type `bool`. Even though it is implementation defined, the C++ standard encourages this implementation.

Comment: If you really want to go ahead with `std::vector<bool> primes(max - min + 1, true)` implementation, then you can solve this by setting an offset. The offset would be equal to `min`. And then while accessing the data of `vector<bool>` you can use `primes.at(i - offset)`

Comment: Thanks for all the help.P.S I was *not* the downvoter

Comment: One last question , why are you using the `template <typename Iterable>` here

Comment: Well that was me, just being lazy. :) There is no good reason, except for the fact that now, the print function can print `std::set` and other iterables as well, which can do `std::cout << i` directly.